# IMAP ip addresses on iphones gmail

Tags: gmail, ip, imap

IF I check my e-mail from my home location in the morning, and throughout the day I am travelling, and by the end of the day I am 30 miles away from home.. At that point 30 miles away from home I check my email, should I still have the same IMAP ip address each time. I am referring to GMAILS recent activity log. Someone help me understand this.

In other words, if im checking my mail on my iphone and never in the same location, should it show a constant ip address, one that is near my home?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  The cell phone network will generally try to maintain your IP address as long as it can, but it may occasionally change.

Comment: how long is that normally, in a big city like dallas

Comment: If you generally remain connected to the cell phone network, possibly days.  If you turn your phone off overnight or something, you may get a new address.